# How to upload multiple image using wp_insert_post

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, gallery, wp-insert-post, post-meta

Im using wp_insert_post to add products on the front end of a woocommerces site

My current code will upload all the images but only the last image will be in the product gallery images

heres my code;

functions.php

```
function my_handle_attachment( $file_handler, $post_id, $set_thu=false) {
  // check to make sure its a successful upload

  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );


  if ( is_numeric( $attach_id ) ) {

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attach_id );

  }
  return $attach_id;  
}
```

frontend

```
if ( $_FILES ) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
            );
            $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                $newupload = my_handle_attachment($file,$post_id);
                 update_post_meta($post_id,  array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery',$newupload));
            }
        }
    }
}


<input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" multiple="multiple"  />
```

Is anything wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Tejas you may please alter your code below and let me know if it worked for you .

```
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) { 

$file = array( 
'name' => $files['name'][$key],
'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
'error' => $files['error'][$key],
'size' => $files['size'][$key]
); 

$_FILES = array ("files" => $file); 
foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) { 
$newupload = my_handle_attachment($file,$post_id); 

}
array_push($gallery,$newupload);

} 
update_post_meta($post_id,'_product_image_gallery', implode(',',$gallery));
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can clean out the title attributes yourself by adding the following to your functions.php file:**

```
function remove_title_attributes($input) {
return preg_replace('/\s*title\s*=\s*(["\']).*?\1/', '', $input);
 }
 add_filter( 'wp_list_pages', 'remove_title_attributes' );
```